# How to set hibernation in apollo ubuntu?

Tags: hibernate

On minipc nexenta S1 I use apollo based Ubuntu from this site

http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.it/

Usually for enable hibernation I use this procedure

a) download pm-utils

```
apt-get -y install pm-utils
```

b) Enable users editing this file

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

with this content

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

c) The last important part..editing /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/sda1"
```

where sda1 is my swap..

I did also

```
update-grub2
```

d) And after reboot...

```
cat /proc/cmdline

\boot\vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic.efi.signed ro root=/dev/mmcblk1p2  quiet splash initrd=boot\initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
```

Why is not affected?

Is for the refi bootloader before grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found

refind bootloader contains the kernel options

so we edit /boot/refind_linux.conf

```
"Boot with standard options"  "ro root=/dev/mmcblk1p2  quiet splash resume=/dev/sda1"
"Boot to single-user mode"    "ro root=/dev/mmcblk1p2  quiet splash single"
"Boot with minimal options"   "ro root=/dev/mmcblk1p2"
```

and works

```
cat /proc/cmdline 
\boot\vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic.efi.signed ro root=/dev/mmcblk1p2  quiet splash resume=/dev/sda1 initrd=boot\initrd.img-4.13.0-16-generic
```